# Google Load Balancer (classic) - change Frontend to support HTTPS redirect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

Having migrated to GCP we're happy with everything until we realised that the HTTP to HTTPS redirect was not happening. This is a checkbox when configuring a frontend and must've been overlooked. It cannot be changed on the existing frontend config now.

The [documentation states](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect#for_existing_load_balancers) for "existing load balancers" that we need to add another load balancer and use that to configure the redirect.

However it seems that I can just configure a new frontend identically to the old frontend (using the same static IP) but with the checkbox ticked, remove the old frontend, save and I'll have what I want.

Is there a reason this plan won't work?

Having just migrated I'm not wanting to risk downtime to try the experiment. Lots of searching has not revealed any similar solutions and shows that load balancer features have been coming thick and fast for the last 4 years and as such most other questions & solutions seem out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just replicated this concern and your option to create new frontend using the same static IP address will actually work. But there will be downtime for at least 5 to 15 minutes.

One of the reason of the downtime is by deleting the old frontend. Creating new frontend while old frontend is ongoing will not work since static IP is in use. Just a reminder, clicking the http - https redirect checkbox is just a shortcut way on creating another load balancer for http - https redirect.

If we are worrying about downtime in adding http - https redirect, the best way to lessen the downtime is by following the [For existing load balancers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect#for_existing_load_balancers) documentation that you also shared.

Comment: Hi Yvan, wow, thanks for the work in answering my question. In clarification, you're saying that no matter what two billable load balancers are created?

Comment: Hi @toxaq, yes. The check box of http - https redirect in frontend configuration is just a short way on creating another load balancer. Once you create a frontend with http - https redirection and once all settings in load balancer is done you will see that there will be two load balancer created. You will identify the load balancer https redirect with the name of the frontend and have "redirection" in the end of the name.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it's not clear from the documentation that this is what's happening. Is there a reason I can't just add an HTTP frontend to the same load balancer and redirect from a rule there?

Comment: Youre welcome. Hmm, adding http frontend in the same load balancer is possible but there will be no redirection will happen. Once you access your domain like this (http://sample.com) it will not redirect to https://sample.com.

Comment: Thanks for your help Yvan. You've clarified the gap in the documentation that the checkbox literally creates another "partial" loadbalancer (whatever partial is taken to mean). Having come from nginx load balancing it is the counter-intuitive nature of GCP's load balancers being HTTP *or* HTTPS that was catching me out.